how to use @Model to get url for src for an image tag
In my project I have an image folder inside of the wwwroot folder of my .net razor pages project.
this image folder is set up like this:
image/
nfl/
logos/
.
.
.
nfl.png
In my index.chtml I know I could just do   to get the nfl.png logo to render. however, when I try to do something like  where LeagueID = "nfl" the picture never loads. does anyone know why?
I have tried to word how the url in the src of the img tag is worded but I just cant get the img to load.

Hi @Michael Brancaleone, what you have done from now on? Did you mean you want to  dynamically load an image based on a variable like LeagueID = "nfl"?

Can you show the actual code you are trying to use?

Try using Url.Content method that will give you path to the static asset:
Url.Content(@"~/image/nfl/logos/...nfl.png");

Example
Having such setup

Below works as desired:
<img src="@Url.Content(@"~/images/piesio_v2.png")" />


If you want to dynamically load an image based on a variable in your Razor Pages project, you could follow the steps:

Ensure your project structure is correct:image/nfl/logos/nfl.png and ensure image src url should be /images/nfl/logos/nfl.png without ~ (F12 in the browser and right-click the image element then choose the inspect to check the src url).


Not sure what is your LeagueID, if it is the value of the logo name without the picture extension, you need configure in Index.cshtml
 @page
 @model YourNamespace.Pages.IndexModel
 @{
     var LeagueID = "nfl"; // This could come from your model or any other source
     var imgSrc = "/images/"+@LeagueID+"/logos/"+@LeagueID + ".png";
 }

 <div>
      <img src="@imgSrc" alt="@LeagueID logo" />
      <img src="@Url.Content(@"~/images/nfl/logos/nfl.png")" />
 </div>



If the LeagueId is from backend, be sure configure the value in PageModel:
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    public string LeagueID { get; set; }

    public void OnGet()
    {
        // Assign the LeagueID from the backend, this is just an example
        LeagueID = "nfl";
    }
}

Then use it in the frontend:
@{
    var imgSrc = "/images/"+Model.LeagueID+"/logos/"+Model.LeagueID + ".png";
}
<img src="@imgSrc" alt="@Model.LeagueID logo" />

